# What is the meaning of "blend in"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "blend in" according to the context of the following sentence?

Now, I just want to do something stupid and mindless, you know? Where I can just like totally blend in.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Blend in* in this context means to become part of your surroundings and not be noticed.  To become "part of the crowd" and not stand out.

In a crowd of people all wearing purple jerseys and baseball caps, if you donned the same and joined the crowd, you'd be *blending in*.

It can also mean doing the same thing or having the same beliefs as everyone else.

Comment: To paraphrase FumbleFingers: "[W]e should seek to discourage people from providing [basic] answers to [basic] questions ... We all like to be helpful, but the place for that level of help is English Language Learners –  FumbleFingers

Comment: Are you suggesting the post be moved to ELL?

Comment: I've already close-voted on that basis; there has been discussion about downvoting even correct answers to questions obviously too basic for ELU (or easily answerable by looking in say a dictionary) given by people with over say 1000 rep points.

Comment: Hi @EdwinAshworth  The expression "blend in" has no clear meaning on the internet.  google translate does not help me. it did not translate it correctly to my native language. Also, some other websites says that it means "to mix" food or something like that. but it does not match the context and that's why I put the total sentence in my question. so I had to ask my question here although I know it is a basic question.

Comment: @user2824371 How do I say 'You're wrong' without sounding confrontational? This is the definition given by [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/blend-in) (on the internet): if someone or something blends in, they are similar to the other people, objects, buildings etc around them, and so they seem appropriate or you do not notice them
... _The new library blends in perfectly with the surrounding buildings._ / 
_Security men were trying to blend in with the crowd._ Cambridge Dictionaries Online gives a very similar definition.

Comment: @DJFar You are welcome to contribute to the discussion that took place / is still taking place? on Meta. '[T]ake it out ...' after 'your' sounds rather personal. There are some here who would just downvote (and I'm beginning to see why) rather than explain. ELU is (still) intended as a site for non-basic English questions; there are many sites for learners. If you can suggest another site for more advanced students, where basic questions are filtered out more satisfactorily, I'd be really interested.